# Deploy asp.net MVC site to IIS7 and use website url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I guess I'm not understanding the logic behind creating a website and adding an application.

In IIS7, I added a website. I also added a binding, say www.website.local:88.

Now I looked at how to import an asp.net project to IIS7 and I had to install "web deploy". Now I can "import" and application...

When I do, it imports into it's own folder in the site's root folder. The problem is, now I have to type www.website.local/application

The application *is* the website and I don't want people to have to navigate *specifically* to the application.

I want people to be able to navigate to www.example.local and have it serve up the application by default.

Why can't I just import an asp.net MVC site *as* a... site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know I should post this as a comment but sadly I don't have enough reputation to post comments...

What you want isn't that hard actually and a simple Google search would take you to the Microsoft documentation where you can find a nice tutorial on how to do this. The tutorial teaches you how to do this on Windows Server and Windows Desktop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis